# Group box isn't parent of controls inside it

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, C++ and use resource editor to to create my dialogs, and I just can't seem to make groupbox actually group the controls inside it so that I could reposition the groupbox (runtime or design time) and make all of its children to move as well. It seems it isn't actually parent of these controls, but how to achieve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Dialog templates are very primitive, don't support 'container controls' like winforms does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ue the Resource Editor for building WinForms applications. Create a new Visual C++/CLR/Windows Forms Application and you'll get a form called Form1. That's WinForms. The Resource Editor is used for plain old Win32 applications and the groupbox there cannot be parent to other controls.